# How to calculate the rest of $2^{p^r-p^{r-1}+1}$ divided by $p^r$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

I have the next problem:

$p$ is an odd prime number and $r$ is a natural number, $r>1$. How can I calculate the rest of the division of $2^{p^r-p^{r-1}+1}$ by $p^r$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\varphi(p^r)=p^r-p^{r-1}$ and $2$ is coprime to $p^r$, so, by Euler-Fermat...?